# How do I fix this php to include full list from array?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, for-loop

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
$array = (explode(":",$row['recent_views']));
   for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
        $userids = $array[$i].',';

 $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE approved = 1 AND id IN(".$userids."0)");  
echo $userids;
//NOTE: my echo is spitting out "18622,44968,44968," but when using $userids in mysql query it doesn't include the full list of numbers
            }   
        }
```

I put }'s after mysql query to try to include variable in the for loop, if i close brackets before query $userids only prints last number from array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the parenthesis before your query and use concatenation instead of re-assigning `$userids` on each iteration:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $array = (explode(":",$row['recent_views']));
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
        $userids .= $array[$i].',';
              // ^ missing the period here
    }
}

$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item LEFT JOIN subcategory
ON item.subcategory_id=subcategory.subcategory_id LEFT JOIN genre ON item.genre_id=genre.genre_id WHERE approved = 1 AND broken = 0 AND id IN(".$userids."0)");  
echo $userids;
```

You could also just get rid of the for-loop and use `implode()`:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $array = (explode(":",$row['recent_views']));
    $userids .= implode(',', $array) + ',';
}
```

While this may fix the issue, know that this isn't very efficient nor maintainable. It would make more sense to use SQL `JOIN` syntax to combine a user's recent views with the sub-categories all in one query.

Comment: I do not understand how to do what you suggest?  can you show an example.

Comment: The implode worked as $userids .= implode(',', $array);  Thanks